# Preview of tables doesn't match the live view

Tags: bug, markdown, markdown-rendering, tables

I went to edit [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68244537/reordering-columns-in-a-table-according-to-a-previously-confirmed-vector) to improve the formatting of the tables, since it looked broken:

[image]

But when I went to edit it, the preview showed it to be correctly formatted:

[image]

This seems to be undesirable since people will presume their tables are formatted correctly and post tables which look like a mess.

It can be fixed by adding an extra line between whatever was preceding the table.